# Where do I get the "types" for certain modules in "firebase"?

Tags: typescript

This is more of a broad question I'm using Firebase as an example for.

In my react project, I might want to `import firebase from "@firebase/app"` which makes sense. But lets say I want this const locationRef to be typed as a firebase ref type. From what do I import "ref" from? Where are these types generally located for any general typescript library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'ref' is not a type in `@firebase/app`. You can check the types from namespace `FirebaseNamespace`